# How do providers plan to deal with rDNS for client /64 IPv6 blocks when assigned?

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, reverse-dns

The standard block assigned to a home will be a /64 block to enable autoconfigure. This means the traditional reverse DNS mapping of host-237.miami.ispname.com is not only practical, it's improbable even if generated automatically with 2^64 entries per client.

Comment: Sixxs only does them for subnets.. `Note that user reverse dns options is only available for subnets and not for tunnels.` http://www.sixxs.net/faq/dns/?faq=reverse

Comment: Ignore it and hope it goes away, seems to be what Comcast has done to date.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually a number of providers who have gone the automated route of generating rDNS, although obviously not with BIND since, whilst it does have a macro that lets you generate a range, it actually iterates and puts every entry in memory, so... doing that on a /64 == crashy crashy.

Firstly, for PowerDNS users there's dyn6 which will generate rDNS for SLAAC hosts, although obviously, this does not cover the entire /64.

A chap from Internode (AU ISP) wrote code into pymds which can generate rDNS on the fly, for an entire subnet, code here: http://code.google.com/p/pymds/